# Is Tevilas Keilim needed?

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping

Regarding a ceramic crock pot that is always used with a plastic liner does it need tevila? or since food never touches pot its fine?
I looked it up

Comment: Even if it has a plastic liner these have been known to split...

Comment: @Dov Food also sometimes falls on my metal wristwatch, but I don't have to tovel it because of unintended accidents.

Comment: Yes but you don't eat from your wristwatch!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Chaim and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Dov I might occasionally lick it if something very delicious spills on it. Same with a crock pot that you always line. Any direct use is incidental and temporary.